# Isn't iPhone SE (3rd generation) a arm64 architecture?

Tags: ios, xcode15

I got this weird error starting an app from Xcode 15 beta 2

> iPhone SE (3rd generation) does not support the architecture of the
> selected executable. Switch to a device that supports arm64.

But SE is arm64 isn't it???

Comment: May be a bug of beta software. Did you check on Apple developer forum ?

Comment: I haven't. thanks